# DateTimeFormater with optional section

Tags: java, datetime-format

I'm writing an application to manipulate text data, Which will change the content of input string and create new output String based on the format of input string.

I encounter some problem with recognized the date time string. Based on the document the input date time may have some optional section, here the sample pattern:

> yyyy[MM[dd[HHmm]]][Z]

So after some digging on the web, my first attempt to use the parseBest function.

```
public boolean checkFormatDate(string input){
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy[MM[dd[HHmm]]][Z]");
    try {
        TemporalAccessor temporalAccessor = formatter.parseBest(input, ZonedDateTime::from, LocalDateTime::from, LocalDate::from);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But the code above failed with these case:

> 1900
>   190001
>   190001011440

My suspect is that the queries that parse the parseBest method is not correct.
Can someone help me with this.

Edit:

Here is the exception log:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '190001011440' could not be parsed at index 0
>      at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1947)
>      at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseBest(DateTimeFormatter.java:1895)

Comment: Could you perhaps catch the exception in such a way that it prints a stack trace so you can see *why* it failed? That usually helps...

Comment: @hmc_jake: I just update the exception log for one of the test case,

Comment: It appears the log is cut off at the end. However, what the log says is that '199012011440' could not be parsed. Why, I'm not sure. It's cut off. (Usually there is a `caused by` clause of a stack trace indicated what went wrong.) However it might help to show what the value of the variable `split` is.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The `split` variable is indeed the `input' variable from the parameter of the function. I change the code again.
So for the stack trace above the input is 190001011440, which is 1st, january 1900, 14:40.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to be the pattern `yyyy`, which is creating a formatter as follows (`System.out.println(formatter)`):

`Value(YearOfEra,4,19,EXCEEDS_PAD)[Value(MonthOfYear,2)[Value(DayOfMonth,2)[Value(HourOfDay,2)Value(MinuteOfHour,2)]]][Offset(+HHMM,'+0000')]`

Note the 4,19 in the first part - minimum width of 4 and max of 19. Build the formatter as follows and it should work:

```
    DateTimeFormatterBuilder b = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder();
    formatter = b.appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR_OF_ERA, 4, 4, SignStyle.EXCEEDS_PAD).appendPattern("[MM[dd[HHmm]]][Z]").toFormatter();
```

Comment: @KDM: Nice catch, as I understand you answer is that the `yyyy` part can be accept 4 to 19 numeric character and because all my input don't have any separator so all the field match only the `yyyy` section right.